# Fundamental JQuery: data-attribute + children() difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fundamental JQuery question... I am trying to get the data-title out of a 2-children nested img tag within a list element.

the HTML looks like this

```
<li>
    <a href="/pages/...">
        <img  src="..." data-title="Norio Matsumoto" /> 
    </a>
    <h4>
        <a href="/pages/..."></a>
        <a href="/pages/..."></a>
    </h4>
</li>
```

Where the img tag is two children deep inside the `<li>`

This is where the interesting thing lies.

I have two variations of JQuery which, to me, seem identical:

1st **is not working**:

```
$(this).children('a img').data('title')
```

2nd **is working**

```
$(this).children('a').children('img').data('title')
```

Isn't writing `children('firstChild nestedChild')` the same as writing `children('firstChild').children('nestedChild')`?

Sincerely,
Confused

**NOTE**

please read the question carefully, I am not looking for code edits or code fixes, I am simply asking a jquery question.

Comment: .children will only return elements that are immediate children of the selected element that match the selector. since the immediate children are anchor tags and not image tags, they were not returned.

Answer (score 4):

The `.children()` function only looks at **immediate** descendants. Because there are no `<img>` tags that are direct descendants of the `<li>`, there'll never be any matches.

This would work:

```
$(this).find('a > img').data('title')
```

though things might get weird if there are more deeply-nested `<a>` + `<img>` groups.

Comment: isnt find() a much slower method than .children().children() since find() has to traverse and children() just goes deeper by one?

Comment: @AlexNeigher that depends on context (how many elements are selected, how many you're selecting, how big the overall dom is, what browser is being used, etc.)

Comment: @AlexNeigher perhaps, but in a modern browser the difference is negligible. Personally I don't like to rely on document structure; it tends to make code pretty fragile.